# Use a plugin's fork for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Instead of using this Jenkins plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/quality-gates-plugin, I am trying to use a forked version of it: https://github.com/sarg/quality-gates-plugin that has some extra functionality.

I've downloaded the forked version as a `.zip` file. I changed the termination of the file from `.zip` to `.hpi`. Then, I added it to Jenkins's `plugins` directory.

This should have installed the plugin, right?

I am looking at installed plugins, but I can't find `Quality Gates Plugin`.

Do I need to do something else to install the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the plugin before uploading / installing the plugin in Jenkins. You do this by unzipping the downloaded zip file. Then, using your favorite terminal or command prompt that has maven on the path, you run `mvn install`. If successful, it will build the .hpi file for the plugin and can be found in the `target` folder, e.g. `target/pluginname.hpi`

For more info on plugin development and building plugins, [look here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-BuildingaPlugin).

Comment: I have problems with `maven` on my local machine. Are there any other options?

Comment: No straight forward way that I know of, you could make Jenkins build it using pipelines or maven job. That way you can get Jenkins to automatically set up maven locally. E.g. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin